# errno 10054 while cloning the repositorium in git from gitlab

Tags: windows, repository, gitlab, git-bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to clone the repositorium in git from gitlab. The command, which I am using is:

```
git clone https://procesttt@gitlab.com...
```

Unfortunately I have got something like this:

```
Cloning into 'testDemo'...
remote: Counting objects: 15529, done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 10054
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: protocol error: bad pack header
```

I am using Windows 10 and git bash. Thank you for the answer. Git version:

```
git version 2.10.1.windows.1
```

Comment: What git version are you using?

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/q/25485816/6309 help?

Comment: git version 2.10.1.windows.1

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to:

- use the latest version of Git for Windows
- force the ssl version (in case [gitlab.com requires a recent tls protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25518086/6309))

  ```
  git config --global http.sslVersion tlsv1.2
  ```

You have other causes (firewall..) [liste here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25496383/6309) for error 10054 .
And I propose some diagnostic helpers in "[Unknown SSL protocol error in connection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20492254/6309)"